# Extracting urls, mentions and hashtags from a tweet

Tags: python, url, twitter, slice, hashtag

I am trying to extract all the characters that are not alphanumeric and also extract url's from a tweet using python. I should only be left with words seperated by spaces.
For example:
If my tweet is : "Hi! Check out my page at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm @python #python"
I should get: "hi check out my page at"
Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is inconsistency in your example, you want to include 'hi' but remove both 'phyton' even though the string 'Hi!' includes non-alphanumeric characters. Are you including the string 'Hi' because it is not a tag like 'phyton'?

Comment: yes I'm including hi because its not a tag, it's a word but I'm getting rid of all the punctuation

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already got the tweet text, then using some of python's built-in operations on strings should be able to do what you're after. Here's a one-liner using list comprehension and the [string.translate module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate):

```
import string

my_tweet = "Hi! Check out my page at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm @phyton #phyton"
tweet_text = ' '.join([i.lower() for i in my_tweet.split() if not i.startswith(('http', '@', '#'))]).translate(None, string.punctuation)
print tweet_text # hi check out my page at
```